# Classes & concurrent futures multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, class

I just started understanding the concept of classes in python and I wish to improve my script. Basically my script checks the status of various URLS using the requests library and does other post processing with the data received. Currently my script is full of functions and am passing around the same parameters to each function. The issue I am facing is I am using concurrent.futures multithreading but am unsure of how can I use it to call a class instead of a function.

I am just doing a simple test below to be able to retrive a dictionary back from the class after processing. However, it is returning me a class object and I can't figure out how to extract the data from the class object.

The purpose of my class is that I want to use it for getting the status of each url and doing some post processing and returning back the dictionary.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class capture_screenshot(object):
    def __init__(self, customer_data):
        self.customer_data = customer_data

    def complex_function(self):
        ....
        self.customer_data = processed_data

url_dict = {"url_0": "https://redacted.com/a", "url_1": "https://redacted.com/b", ...}

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor:
    processed_results = list(executor.map(capture_screenshot, url_dict.items()))

print(processed_results) # This should be "https://redacted.com/a but I am getting a class object
```

```
processed_results : [<capture_screenshot object at 0x0000020443...>, <capture_screenshot object at 0x0000020443...>]
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _it is returning me a class object_ ? Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: @AMC I have amended the code as per your request.

Comment: That’s not classes, those are the instances. You haven’t defined a representation.

Comment: What is the purpose of your classes? They are currently just a convoluted way to store a value.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ok say they are instances, but what do you mean by representation?

Comment: See the docs on the ˋ__repr__ˋ and ˋ__str__ˋ methods. They define how instances are displayed.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have edited my question to reflect what I am actually trying to achieve.

Comment: From your description, it seems like a class is not appropriate. In General, if a class has only ˋ__init__ˋ and ˋ__call__ˋ, it is a convoluted way to define a function.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi alright, appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `processed_results = list(executor.map(capture_screenshot, url_dict))` just initializes the object (calls the `__init__` method).
That is why you receive objects.

I think you also need to execute the objects after initialization.
Try maybe something like this:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor:
    processed_results = list(executor.map(capture_screenshot, url_dict.items()))

results = [res.customer_data for res in processed_results]
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it works perfectly, thanks!